# How to override abstract base class behavior with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have code like this:

```
class Outer {
  private External external;
  class MyCallback extends ExternalAbstractCallback {
    void somethingHappened() { if (super.someCondition()) { ... }; }
  }

  public Outer() {
     external = ...;
  }

  public setExternal(External e) { external = e; } // test support

  public void doIt() {
    external.setCallback(new MyCallback());
    external.doSomething();
  }
}
```

I want to test the behavior of `MyCallback` when `doIt()` is called.  I use Mockito to create a mock External and can then get `external.doSomething()` to execute the MyCallback.somethingHappened.  Can I control the return value of the call to `super.someCondtion` at line 4?  Can I rearrange the implementation to improve testability?  The implementations of `External` and `ExternalAbstractCallback` cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you can't mock `new` with Mockito. In a nutshell, code that you want to test should never call `new`.

Workarounds:

- Add a getter/setter for the callback.
- Move `new MyCallback()` into a new protected helper method which you override in your test

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.  But adding a getter/setter for MyCallback seems impossible, since MyCallback is an inner class.

Comment: What stops you from extracting the inner class?

Comment: So? Make the things that you need to mutate [package private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private).